# Fast way of computing Inverse EDF in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab

I am running the following code to obtain the values of the inverse EDF of a data Matrix at the data points:

```
function [mOUT] = InvEDF (data)

% compute inverse of EDF at data values
% function takes T*K matrix of data and returns T*K matrix of transformed
% data, keepin the order of the original series

T = rows(data);
K = cols(data);
mOUT=zeros(T,K);

for j = 1:K 

    for i = 1:T
        temp = data(:,j)<=data(i,j);
        mOUT(i,j) = 1/(T+1)*sum(temp); 
    end

end
```

The data Matrix is usually of size 1000*10 or even 1000*30 and I am calling this function a few thousand times. Is there a faster way of doinf this? Any answers are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the values and use the index in the sorted matrix as the count of values less or equal. We treat each column by itself, so I will illustrate on a Mx1 matrix.

```
A = rand(M,1);
[B,I] = sort(A);
C(I) = 1:M;
```

`C(i)` will now contain the count of values less or equal to `A(i)`. If you can have duplicate values you need to take that into account.

The advantage of this approach is that we can do it in O(M log M) time, whereas your original inner loop is O(M^2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
mOUT=zeros(T,K);
for j = 1:K
    d1 = data(:,j);
    mOUT(:,j) = sum(bsxfun(@ge,d1,d1'),2); %%//'
end
mOUT = mOUT./(T+1);
```